# SharePoint 2016 MySite Error - We're having trouble loading some parts of this page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, mysite

I provisioned My Site Host in a new SharePoint 2016 environment. The root site is not loading and throws the following error:
*We're having trouble loading some parts of this page, but your documents aren't affected. While we work on fixing it, you can continue using your documents like you normally would.*
Tried the following with no success:
IISreset,
Cleared config cache,
Rebooted the server,
Rebuilt My Site web application.
I do not see anything relevant except distributed cache related errors in ULS logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could re-create user profile service application and MySite.

And you also could follow the troubleshooting steps in the article below.

SharePoint 2016 : Resolve UPA Endpoint Issue.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38312.sharepoint-2016-resolve-upa-endpoint-issue.aspx

You could click the Checkmark as the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Amy that worked.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as an answer.

Comment: Would love to, but I don't see the mark as answer button.

Comment: you could follow the steps to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers